# Fetching values from an element in an iframe on the same domain

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I'm trying to condense two processes down in to one by having the two pages I need on one page using an iframe.

I have a page that contains a text area (used for sending an email) and then I have a purchase reference page that contains the details of someones purchase.

I'm trying to append an iframe of the purchase page to the bottom of my email page and then grab some data that's on it and insert it in to the text area.

**EDIT**: This is what I have so far:

**Script one**

```
//Grabs the selected purchase number
var purchaseNumber = window.getSelection();
purchaseNumber = purchaseNumber.toString();

var purchaseTitle;
var purchaseNumber;

function frameLoaded() {
           purchaseTitle = window.frames['purchaseIframe'].contentDocument.getElementById ('listingTitle');
           purchaseNumber = window.frames['purchaseIframe'].contentDocument.getElementById ('auctionSoldIdDisplay');
           purchaseTitle = purchaseTitle.innerHTML;
           purchaseNumber = purchaseNumber.innerHTML

var purchaseDetails = purchaseTitle + " - " + purchaseNumber;

insertText = insertText.replace("PURCHASEDETAILS", purchaseDetails);
         }  

if(purchaseNumber.length > 0){

var purchaseIframe = document.createElement('iframe');
purchaseIframe.src = 'http://www.mysite.co.nz/Admin/Listing/PurchaseDisplay.aspx?asid=' + purchaseNumber + '&submit1=++GO++';
purchaseIframe.setAttribute("height","1000");
purchaseIframe.setAttribute("width","100%");
purchaseIframe.setAttribute("id","purchaseIframe");
purchaseIframe.setAttribute("onload", "frameLoaded();");
void(document.body.appendChild(purchaseIframe));
alert(purchaseNumber); 
}
```

**Script Two**

```
//Gather the selected template
var selectedTxt = document.getElementById('txtEmailText').value;

//Change the selected txt to a string
var insertText = selectedTxt.toString();

var purchaseTitle = window.frames['purchaseIframe'].contentDocument.getElementById ('listingTitle');
var purchaseNumber = window.frames['purchaseIframe'].contentDocument.getElementById ('auctionSoldIdDisplay');

purchaseTitle = purchaseTitle.innerHTML;
purchaseNumber = purchaseNumber.innerHTML

var purchaseDetails = purchaseTitle + " - " + purchaseNumber;

insertText = insertText.replace("PURCHASEDETAILS", purchaseDetails);


//Pasting the variable in to the textarea
document.getElementById('txtEmailText').value = insertText;
```

Effectively I am highlighting the purchase reference number on the page then executing this script to open the purchase page using the highlighted number. I am then grabbing the text values of the elements I need and pasting them in to the text area.

I'm still pretty new to javascript and am teaching myself as I go.

If i run the above scripts one after the other then it works like a charm, however if I try to run them together with the second in an onload() function set to the iframe then it won't.

Any help would be greatly appreciated or if you could point me in the direction of an article to help.

Answer (score 0):

My first thought is that the iframe is not fully loaded before you try to get the values from it. My thought would be to try adding an onload event to your iframe and then when it loads invoke a function that grabs the value.

I would add `purchaseIframe.setAttribute("onload", "frameLoaded();");` to your purchaseIframe block and then add the frameLoaded() function to your script. something like:

```
      function frameLoaded() {
            var purchaseTitle = window.frames[0].document.getElementById("listingTitle" );
            var purchaseNumber = window.frames[0].document.getElementById("auctionSoldIdDisplay");
            console.log(purchaseTitle.innerHTML);
            console.log(purchaseNumber.innnerHTML);
         }
```

And see if something like that grabs the right values. If it does than you can plug it in where you need it.

Am I understanding your problem correctly?

Comment: I added in your code and I'm still running in to an error:
     Uncaught ReferenceError: purchaseTitle is not defined
VM773:8 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null

Comment: But you have the right idea, I want to load the iframe and then grab the values in to global variables that I later use

Comment: Hmm. Maybe if you re-arrange the it like this it will give you a value:         `function frameLoaded() { 
            var theFrame = window.frames[0];
            var purchaseTitle = theFrame.document.getElementById("listingTitle" ); 
            var purchaseNumber = theFrame.document.getElementById("auctionSoldIdDisplay"); 
            console.log(purchaseTitle.innerHTML); 
            console.log(purchaseNumber.innerHTML); 
         }`

Comment: This has worked for me in all of my testing for grabbing innerHTML of an element in an iframe.

Comment: Sorry mate, I've just been scouring over the code because it should've worked and a modified version of what you gave me is now working! I'll post my solution shortly

Comment: Glad I could steer you in the right direction. I wasn't expecting mine to work. It works on all of my examples, but you have more going on. You probably had to put most a lot of your other code inside the function, and their are different functions like `contentDocument` that could be used.

Comment: Sorry mate, I thought it was going but it isn't quite. 
I have no clue why, but if I run the first one and then the second it works, but not if I try them together